# How can I combine the numbers that are adjacent in the array into single numbers and return an array with "5", "6", "7, "8", "9", "10", "11"?

Tags: javascript

["5", "", "6", "", "7", "", "8", "", "9", "", "1", "0", "", "1", "1"]
How do I change this array so that adjacent elements that are both numbers like "1", "0" are converted into single numbers like "10"? I want the final array to have ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried

Comment: `reduce` would be the best bet, but you can also try `.join(' ').replace(/\s(\S)/g,"$1").split(' ')`

Comment: hey @pawel can you please post an answer with reduce ...with reduce i have been trying as `var result = numbers.filter(Boolean).reduce((prev,curr)=>((prev=="0"&&curr=="1")||(prev=="1"&&curr=="0")||curr==prev)?curr=curr+prev:curr) ` ... gives `11` , only last ...

Comment: @Codenewbie please edit the question and include this attempt.

Comment: i was just trying to learn ... Questioner might already got solution from join u mentioned

Comment: @pawel Thank you! The .join part worked.  Could you breakdown the regex expression and explain what it does?

Comment: @Codenewbie sorry, I didn't notice you were not the OP :)

Answer (score 2):

The split/replace/join comment was a bit tongue in cheek, but this is how it works. Given `arr = ["5", "", "6", "", "7", "", "8", "", "9", "", "1", "0", "", "1", "1"]`

```
.join(' ') // now we have a string "5  6  7  8  9  1 0  1 1"
```

There are two spaces between 5, 6, 7... and only a single space between 1 0 and 1 1.

```
.replace(/\s(\S)/g,"$1")
```

This replaces spaces `\s` followed by non-spaces `\S` with the non-space match, i.e. `" 0"` with `"0"`

```
 .split(' ')
```

Use the remaining single spaces to convert it back to an array.

A real example using Array.prototype.reduce:

```
const numbers = ["5", "", "6", "", "7", "", "8", "", "9", "", "1", "0", "", "1", "1"].reduce( (acc, cur) => {
  if( cur === ""){ // if current item is an empty string, create a new placeholder
     return [...acc, ""]
  }
  else {  // otherwise append the current number to last entry
     acc[acc.length-1] += cur;
     return acc;
  }
}, [""]) // initialize with an empty string
```

In the first iteration `acc` is `[""]`, we hit a `5` so we add it to the last element of `acc`, `"" += 5`, now we have `acc === ["5"]`.
The next iteration hits a `""`, now `acc === ["6", ""]` etc
When it's at `["5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "1"]` we hit a non-empty string so we add it to the existing `"1"`, i.e. `"1" += "0" = "10"`.

Comment: Thanks a ton mate :) very well explained !!

Comment: @pawel Thanks so much for the detailed explanation! It really helped :)